# My disk doesn't want to unlock encryption

Tags: debian, encryption, disk-encryption, dm-crypt

I use Debian default encryption disk encryption. When I boot I need to type my password, and then I will be logged in. However today I can't login. It always says that I typed the wrong password, but I typed the correct password.

I tried to boot in live-CD and try unlock volume from there. But It always says wrong password. What is this? How to fix this?

I had an achieve that had a 90GB file in it and I tried to underachieve it, but it gave me error not enough space. I get notification that I'm out of space 600mb left, but when type `df -h` I saw I have same amount of space as before I start to unarchieving file. Looks like file was autodeleted by Debian system.

[image: screenshot]

When I try to boot like this [image: grub1] I get this [image]
When I boot like this [image: grub2] I get [image] and this [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103364/discussion-on-question-by-user390072-my-disk-doesnt-want-to-unlock-encryption).